# Getting undefined in Dom but value available in Console

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

```js
 $(function () {
        var people = [];
        var ctCells = [], questionCells = [], userCells = [];
        var $tBody = $("#userdata tbody");
        $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/18g7fm', function (data) {
            $.each(data.ct_info, function (i, f) {
                ctCells.push(`<td id=${f.id}>${f.id}</td><td>${f.name}</td>`);
                var users = []
                var question = []
                f.Qid_info.forEach((x) => {
                    x.user_info.forEach((y) => {
                        //avoid duplicates
                        var foundUser = users.find((user) => {
                            return user.id === y.id
                        })
                        if (!foundUser) {
                            users.push(y)
                        }
                    })
                })
                f.Qid_info.forEach((x) => {
                    var foundQuestion = question.find((questions) => {
                        return questions.id === x.id
                    })
                    if (!foundQuestion) {
                        question.push(x)
                    }
                })
                $.each(question, function (i, question) {
                    ctCells.push(`<td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>`)
                    questionCells.push(`<td id=${question.id}>${question.id}</td><td>${question.isActive}</td><td>${question["is complex"]}</td><td>${question["is breakdown"]}</td>`);

                })
               
                $.each(users, function (i, user) {
                    var a = user.data.map(function (key) {
                        return key
                    })
                
                    // ctCells.push(`<td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>`)
                    // questionCells.push(`<td colspan="${lent+1}">&nbsp;</td>`)
                    
                    userCells.push(`<td><div style="display:flex; flex-direction:row">
                        ${
                            users.forEach(val => {
                                `<div style="display:flex; flex-direction:column">
                                  <div>${val.id}${val.name}</div>
                                    <div>${val.updatedAt}</div>
                                    <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:column">
                                      
                                            ${user.data.forEach(IN => {
                                               `  
                                                <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:row">
                                                  <div><p>${console.log(IN.git_ids)}</p></div>
                                                
                                                    </div>
                                                    
                                                    `
                                            })}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>`
                            })
                        }
                        </div></td>`)
                //     userCells.push(`<td id=${user.id}>UserId---&nbsp;&nbsp;${user.id}&nbsp;&nbsp; UserName----&nbsp;&nbsp;${user.name}${a.map(value => {
                //         return `
                //                 <div id="${user.id}" >
                //                         <td><input type="checkbox" style="display: inline;"> </td>
                //                         <td> <span id="text">${Object.keys(value)[0]}</span></td>
                //                         <td> <textarea type="text" class="gitplc" placeholder="GitId">${ value.git_ids}</textarea> </td> j
                //                 </div>
                //           `
                //     })
                //         }</td><td>${user.updatedAt}</td>`);
                })
            });
        console.log(userCells)
            $.each(ctCells, function (i) {
        console.log(userCells)
                
                $tBody.append(`<tr>${ctCells[i]}${questionCells[i]}${userCells[i]}</tr>`)
            })


        });
    });
```

```css
 #scrlSec {
        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;

    }

    /* .checkSec { width: 60%;  } */
    .checkSec .tbl {
        padding-top: 20px;
    }

    .checkSec td {
        padding-left: 10px;
    }

    .checkSec .btnGreen {
        color: white;
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        border: none;
        padding: 15px 32px;
        width: 100%;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .checkSec .gitplc {
        width: 80%;
    }

    .checkSec #text {
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    .checkSec .tbl .colOne {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
    }

    .checkSec .tbl .colTwo {
        width: 50%;
        float: right;
    }

    #user {
        overflow: auto;
    }

    .flex-container {
        display: flex;
    }

    th,
    td {
        font-weight: normal;
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 120px;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    th {
        background: #00B0F0;
    }

    tr+tr th,
    tbody th {
        background: #DAEEF3;
    }

    tr+tr,
    tbody {
        text-align: left
    }

    table,
    th,
    td {
        border: solid 1px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        table-layout: fixed;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='userdata'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2" id="ct">CT INFO</th>
                <th colspan="4" id="que">Question</th>
                <th id="user">User Info</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>CT ID</th>
                <th>CT</th>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>isActive</th>
                <th>is Complex</th>
                <th>is Breakdown</th>
                <th>USER</th>
                
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I am printing json data in table format in html. But in users column i am getting undefined but when i print those variable in  console that is printing correct value. 
This is my json api . When i print value in foreach loop of user  i am getting undefined but on console.log i have proper value printing in console. 
https://api.myjson.com/bins/18g7fm

[image: va]

Comment: Keep in mind that what console.log is showing is lazily evaluated in your browser. It doesn't necessarily show the value as its used in your code at runtime. To see the exact value as your lines of code are seeing it, try to use your browser's javascript debugger. You can set breakpoints in certain lines, stop the script execution, and look at all the variables at this moment in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are using `forEach()` inside a template literal. `forEach()` returns undefined by default. Use `map()` function instead.

```
userCells.push(`<td><div style="display:flex; flex-direction:row">
                        ${
                            users.map(val => {
                                return `<div style="display:flex; flex-direction:column">
                                  <div>${val.id}${val.name}</div>
                                    <div>${val.updatedAt}</div>
                                    <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:column">

                                            ${user.data.map(IN => {
                                              return `  
                                                <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:row">
                                                  <div><p>${console.log(IN.git_ids)}</p></div>

                                                    </div>

                                                    `
                                            })}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>`
                            })
                        }
                        </div></td>`)
```

Comment: Thanyou @kalimah.... you saved my ton of time. And it worked fine too